# Shell Script Variable Scope with commnd

Tags: bash, shell, variables, scope, command

I came across an interesting thing in Shell Scripting and not 100% sure why the behaviour is like this

I tried the below script:

```
#!/bin/sh
CMD="curl -XGET http://../endpoint";
var1=eval $CMD | sed -e 's/find/replace/g';
echo $var1;  # Output: printed the value on this line
echo $var1;  # Output: blank/no data printed (Why it is blank?)
```

I had to change the command in variable enclosing with back-tick ` to print the variable as many time as I wanted.

```
CMD="curl -XGET http://../endpoint";
var1=`eval $CMD | sed -e 's/find/replace/g'`;
echo $var1;  # Output: printed the value on this line 
echo $var1;  # Output: printed the value on this line
```

- Why I have to surround my command with ` to assign it's o/p to the variable in subsequent variable usage?

I have a feeling that it has something to do with the variable-command scope.

Shedding light on my understanding will be appreciated!

UPDATE:
I tried the below command and it is working in my env.

```
#!/bin/sh
CMD="curl -XGET http://www.google.com/";
var1=eval $CMD | sed -e 's/find/replace/g';
echo $var1;  # Output: printed the value on this line
echo "######";
echo $var1;  # Output: blank/no data printed (Why it is blank?)
```

Comment: Note that the '$(...)' syntax is preferred over the backtick syntax. Here is an explanation: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/082

Comment: Thanks pmohandas for the suggestion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

sh/bash allows you to run a command with a variable in its environment, without permanently modifying the variable in the shell. This is great, because you can e.g. run a command in a certain language just one time without having to change your entire user's or system's language:

```
$ LC_ALL=en_US.utf8 ls foo
ls: cannot access foo: No such file or directory
$ LC_ALL=nb_NO.utf8 ls foo
ls: cannot access foo: Ingen slik fil eller filkatalog
```

However, this means that when you try to do

```
var=this is some command
```

you're trigger this syntax.

It means "run the command `is a command` and tell it that the variable `var` is set to `this`"

It does not assign "this is my string" to the variable, and it definitely does not evaluate "this is a string" as a command, and then assign its output to `var`.

Given this, we can look at what actually happened:

```
CMD="curl -XGET http://../endpoint";
var1=eval $CMD | sed -e 's/find/replace/g';  # No assignment, output to screen
echo $var1;  # Output: blank/no data printed
echo $var1;  # Output: blank/no data printed
```

There is no scope issue and no inconsistency: the variable is never assigned, and is never written by an echo statement.

`` var=`some command` `` (or preferably, `var=$(some command)`) works because this is valid syntax to assign output from a program to a variable.

Comment: aaha, if that is the case then let me run a test to confirm my understanding. Thannks. I will let you know.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks. That 'echo' statement confused me. When I remove 'echo' I still see command o/p. This makes sense now. Thank!

Answer (score 1):

The first example isn't doing what you think it is.

Neither echo is printing anything. Make them `echo "[$var1]"` to see that.

You need the backticks to *run* the command and capture its output.

Your first attempt was running the `$CMD | sed -e 's/find/replace/g';` pipeline with the environment of `$CMD` containing `var1` set to a value of `eval`.

You also shouldn't be putting commands inside strings (or using `eval` in general). See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001 for more on why.

Comment: Don't play games with echo. Run the lines like I said so you can see what each echo outputs. Alternatively, put a sleep between the `$CMD` line and the first `echo` line. The `echo` is *not* printing anything.

Comment: Thanks Etan! I understood it now.